# Equivalence Classes and Quotient Algebras

Tags: equivalence-relations, algebras

I'm reading through this book: Algebras of Linear Transformations. Here is an image of a short passage: [image].

I'm struggling to show that the multiplication of equivalence classes ([$a_1$][$a_2$] = [$a_1 a_2$]) is well-defined. Note: I changed $x$ to be $a_1$ and $y$ to be $a_2$ from the book, because using the definition of $[x]$ gets confusing for me.

I know that I need to show that [$a_1$][$a_2$] = [$a_1^\prime$][$a_2^\prime$]. I'd really appreciate some direction regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not even trying to prove the right thing.

Given the definitions in the image, to prove that $[x][y]$ is well defined can be done by showing that, if $[a] = [a']$ and $[b] = [b']$ then $[ab] = [a'b']$ (the product doesn't depend on the choice of the elements in each equivalence class).

So suppose $[a] = [a']$ and $[b] = [b']$, that is, $a - a' \in \mathfrak{I}$ and $b - b' \in \mathfrak{I}$.
First, we see that $ab - a'b = (a - a')b \in \mathfrak{I}$, because $a - a' \in \mathfrak{I}$ and $\mathfrak{I}$ is an ideal.
So $[ab] = [a'b]$.
Similarly, $a'b - a'b' \in \mathfrak{I}$, whence $[a'b] = [a'b']$.

By transitivity, $[ab] = [a'b']$.

Comment: Great solution! Much appreciated. I came up with: $a_1\sim a_1^\prime \implies a_1^\prime-a_1=y\in\mathfrak{F} \implies a_1^\prime=a_1+y$. Similarly, $a_2\sim a_2^\prime \implies a_2^\prime-a_2=z\in\mathfrak{F} \implies a_2^\prime=a_2+z$. Then
\begin{align*}
a_1^\prime a_2^\prime - a_1a_2 &= (a_1+y)(a_2+z)-a_1a_2\\
&=a_1z+ya_2+yz.
\end{align*}
Since $a_1,a_2\in\mathfrak{A}$ and $y,z\in\mathfrak{F}$, it follows that $a,z\in\mathfrak{F}$, $ya_2\in\mathfrak{F}$, and $yz\in\mathfrak{F}$. Since $\mathfrak{F}$ is an ideal $a_1z+ya_2+yz\in\mathfrak{F} \implies a_1a_2 \sim a_1^\prime a_2^\prime$.